# Is it a Ruby on Rails thing that POST to /users is a Create action? (not POST to /users/create)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, ruby-on-rails-3, cakephp, rest

I found it a bit hard to understand that Ruby on Rails won't POST to

```
/users/create
```

for the `UsersController#create` (`users` controller, `create` action).  But instead, the standard for its RESTful resource routes is to POST to

```
/users
```

Is it only true for Rails or is it standard among RESTful routes, and used as a common standard?  (such as even for Django or CakePHP?)

Comment: Django itself doesn't care about REST. You can do what ever you like. It's a general framework. If you were to implement a REST interface in django, you'd be advised to follow the REST convention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [typical REST convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#RESTful_web_services). All frameworks that implement REST (correctly) will do this. You can think of it as the POSTing to the collection and that POST requests hold some agreement that a non idempotent creation of an entry will occur.